# Cannot use offsets when Element Array Buffer Object is disabled error in OpenGL(Java)

Tags: java, opengl

I was  trying to create a square on the screen and texture it when I ran into this problem, "Cannot use offsets when Element Array Buffer Object is disabled". The Error comes from the line,

```
GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES,model.getVertexCount(),GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
```

Here is some of my code:

The Renderer Method:

This renders stuff

```
RawModel model = texturedModel.getRawmodel();
GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVaoID());
GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D,texturedModel.getTexture().getID());
GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES,model.getVertexCount(),GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

The bindIndicesBuffer method:

This creates a vbo, binds it, and unbinds it at the end of the method

```
int vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
vbos.add(vboID);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
IntBuffer buffer = putIndicesInIntBuffer(indices);
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

I noticed that when I Remove the line,

```
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

The program will not give me this error

I think it would be inefficient to leave a bound vbo bound without unbinding it but I am not sure

Should I work out another fix or just have the vbo stay bound.

I know there is some questions that address this problem but, they did not help that much.

I am sorry if I am being stupid about this problem. I am a opengl noob and I am following along in a tutorial series so I do not fully completely understand all of this code. :(

Answer (score 1):

Element buffers are part of VAO state. Thus, when you bound it, you were really attaching it to the VAO. So when you unbound it, you put no element buffer in the VAO. Then you tried to do indexed rendering with no element buffer attached to the VAO.

So yes, you need to leave the element buffer attached to the VAO.